# ReactJS - Props and classes

Tags: reactjs

I am really new to React, so I am trying to build a Pokemon app. My main goal is to build the list of 20 pokemon, and detail box which when clicked on Pokemon from the list should display chosen pokemon details, pictures etc.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles/App.css';

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return <div className="App">
            <h1> Pokedex! </h1>
            <PokemonList/>
            <PokemonDetail/>
        </div>;
    }
}

class Pokemon extends Component {
    render(){
        const {pokemon,id} = this.props;
        return <div className="pokemon--species">
            <button className="pokemon--species--container">
                <div className="pokemon--species--sprite">
                    <img src={`https://pokeapi.co/media/sprites/pokemon/${id}.png`} />
                </div>
                <div className="pokemon--species--name">{id} {pokemon.name} {pokemon.url} </div>
            </button>
        </div>;
    }
}

class PokemonDetail extends Component {
    render(){
        const {pokemon, id} = this.props;
        return <div className="pokemon--species">
            <button className="pokemon--species--container">
                <div className="pokemon--species--sprite">
                    <img src={`https://pokeapi.co/media/sprites/pokemon/${id}.png`} />
                </div>
                <div className="pokemon--species--name">{id}</div>
                <p>Attack:72</p>
                <p>Defense:23</p>
                <p>Health:99</p>
            </button>
        </div>;
    }
}

class PokemonList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            species : [],
            fetched : false,
            loading : false,
        };
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            loading : true
        });
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20').then(res=>res.json())
            .then(response=>{
                this.setState({
                    species : response.results,
                    loading : true,
                    fetched : true
                });
            });
    }

    render(){
        const {fetched, loading, species} = this.state;
        let content ;
        if(fetched){
            content = <div className="pokemon--species--list">{
                species.map((pokemon,index) => <Pokemon key={pokemon.name} id={index+1} pokemon={pokemon}/>)
            }
            </div>;
        }else if(loading && !fetched){
            content = <p> Loading ...</p>;
        }
        else{
            content = <div/>;
        }
        return  <div className="container">
            {content}
        </div>;
    }
}



export default App;
```

I know, there is much to do there, but first I want to understand how to pass ID to pokemondetails class.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params) and [how to pass parameters to components associated with routes](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/quick-start.md). Basically, you could have two routes that would render following components `PokemonList` and `PokemonDetail`. Redirect user from the `PokemonList` to `PokemonDetail` and append `pokemonId` to the url ( e.g "/details/23").
After redirection 'PokemonDetail' component would be rendered and `pokemonId` would be available in the component.

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
    ...
      <Route exact path="/" component={PokemonList}/>
      <Route path="/details/:pokemonId" component={PokemonDetail}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

// access pokemonId
class PokemonDetail extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.params.pokemonId}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```